# How to use nsdialogs REMOVE or REPAIR feature in NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

My installer working fine without nsdialogs, If i add nsdialogs its not working good.I can't call nsdialogs in correct place.where i need to call nsdialogs?

```
Var hwnd
Var Dialog
Page custom checkinstall 
Page custom nsDialogsPage
.
.
.
Function .onInit

!define MUI_LANGDLL_ALWAYSSHOW
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
SetShellVarContext all
!insertmacro VerifyUserIsAdmin
FunctionEnd
```

Function un.onInit
    !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
    SetShellVarContext all

```
SetRebootFlag true

MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "Are you sure you want to uninstall 
${APPNAME}?" IDOK next
Abort
next:
!insertmacro VerifyUserIsAdmin
FunctionEnd


Function un.onUninstSuccess
HideWindow
MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "$(^Name) was successfully removed 
from your computer."
FunctionEnd

Function Repair
Call .onInit
FunctionEnd

Function Remove
ExecWait "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
FunctionEnd

Function checkinstall
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM \
"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
"UninstallString"
IfFileExists $R0 +1 NotInstalled
Call nsDialogsPage
NotInstalled:
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog
${If} $Dialog == error
    Abort
${EndIf}
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
    Pop $hwnd
    ${NSD_AddStyle} $hwnd ${WS_GROUP}
    ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd Repair
 ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
    Pop $hwnd
    ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd Remove
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

I can not call nsdialogs correctly. checkinstall function not working at all.I need a correct solution for that.

Comment: Posting partial code is often not enough. How are you writing UninstallString?

Comment: WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

Comment: Sir, immediately i need a script,can you send nsdialogs sample script for repair and remove the installer

Comment: No, I said UninstallString, not WriteUninstaller. If you want help you need to post code that is somewhat complete so I can compile it.

Comment: ok sir i will post my full script

Comment: sir i can not add codes.please can you write a simple nsdialogs script for repair and remove features while replace or overwrite the installer.

Comment: I just want to see the line where UninstallString is written to the registry, why is that so hard?

Comment: WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\VCollab Suite" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"'

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the uninstall command to the registry with quotes (correct) but you are not removing the quotes when reading the value so the file exists test is always going to be false.

You should remove the quotes from commands you read from the registry:

```
Function GetAppFromCommand
Exch $1
Push $2
Push $3
StrCpy $3 ""
StrCpy $2 $1 1
StrCmp $2 '"' qloop sloop
sloop:
    StrCpy $2 $1 1 $3
    IntOp $3 $3 + 1
    StrCmp $2 "" +2
    StrCmp $2 ' ' 0 sloop
    IntOp $3 $3 - 1
    Goto done
qloop:
    StrCmp $3 "" 0 +2
    StrCpy $1 $1 "" 1 ; Remove initial quote
    IntOp $3 $3 + 1
    StrCpy $2 $1 1 $3
    StrCmp $2 "" +2
    StrCmp $2 '"' 0 qloop
done:
StrCpy $1 $1 $3
Pop $3
Pop $2
Exch $1
FunctionEnd
!macro GetAppFromCommand cmd outvar
Push `${cmd}`
Call GetAppFromCommand
Pop ${outvar}
!macroend

Function checkinstall
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM \
"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
"UninstallString"
!insertmacro GetAppFromCommand $R0 $R0
IfFileExists $R0 +1 NotInstalled
Call nsDialogsPage
NotInstalled:
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: @ARAVINTH If it worked then you should mark it as the answer by clicking the "v" under the vote buttons.